# React - wrap variable component inside of a parent div?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that renders sections, and how each section is rendered is based on what type of section it is. If the section is textWithImage for example, return:

```
case 'textWithImage':
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.section.text}</div>
        <img src={this.props.section.imageURL} />
      </div>
    )
```

I also have a section that is a setOfThree, where there are 3 elements like textWithImage inside a parent section, setOfThree. Here is my current code:

```
case 'setOfThree':
      return (
        this.props.section.elements.map((element) => {
          switch (element.type) {
            case 'picture':
              return <img key={element.id} src={element.imageURL} />
            case 'headline':
              return (
                <div key={element.id}>
                  <h2>{element.headline}</h2>
                  <div>{element.description}</div>
                </div>
              )
            case 'blobWithHeadline':
              return (
                <div key={element.id}>
                  <h2>{element.headline}</h2>
                  <div>{element.blob}</div>
                </div>
              )
            case 'imageWithDescription':
              return (
                <div>
                  <div key={element.id}>{element.text}</div>
                  <img src={element.imageURL} />
                </div>
              )
          }
        })
      )
  default:
    return (
      <div>testing</div>
    )
}
}
```

I would like the sectionofThree to have a parent div surrounding all of the sub-elements so I can use flexbox on the sectionOfThree. How would I wrap all the sub-elements inside a parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you could just wrap it like below:

```
let subElements = [];
switch( ... ) {
     // ...
   case 'textWithImage':
       return(<div>
           <div>{this.props.section.text}</div>
           <img src={this.props.section.imageURL} />
       </div>));
       break;

   case 'setOfThree':
       return (<div className = "parent">
           {this.props.section.elements.map((element) => {
               switch (element.type) {
                   case 'picture':
                       return (<img key={element.id} src={element.imageURL} />);
                   case 'headline':  
                       return(
                           <div key={element.id}>
                               <h2>{element.headline}</h2>
                               <div>{element.description}</div>
                       </div>);
                       break;
                   case 'blobWithHeadline':
                       retrun(
                           <div key={element.id}>
                               <h2>{element.headline}</h2>
                               <div>{element.blob}</div>
                       </div>);
                       break;
                   case 'imageWithDescription':
                       retrun (
                           <div>
                               <div key={element.id}>{element.text}</div>
                               <img src={element.imageURL} />
                       </div>);
                       break;
               }
           })}</div>);
     //...
   default:
       break;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I only want to wrap the setOfThree inside a parent div. Since the other types of sections besides setOfThree are not nested, I can structure them as I want. But with setOfThree, I want to wrap the 3 sub-elements in a parent. Does that make sense?